# Managing identities in Gnus

Tags: email, emacs, gnus

What's the simplest way to manage sending identities in Emacs Gnus for email? I'm used to Thunderbird, but I'm trying to migrate to something a little less heavy and unportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your address, and organization *etc.* based upon the newsgroup/mail folder you are in via [Posting Styles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Posting-Styles.html).

Comment: Posting Styles apply when you're replying to a message. When you're composing a new one, you have to «manually» switch posting styles. I've noticed several packages (https://github.com/renard/gnus-identities/blob/master/gnus-identities.el for instance) but it seems gnus doesn't prove a interactive switch-posting-style out of the box. Does it ?